# Правильно ли я проверяю переменную на целое число?

Tags: php

Добрый день.
Стоит задача: проверить, является ли переменная целым числом.
В системе переменная может быть либо `integer` (тогда всё окей), либо `array` (делаем проверку), либо `string` (делаем проверку). Использую такой код для проверки:

```
function isint($var){
    if(is_array($var) && count($var)===1){
        if(is_int($var[0])){
            return true;
        }
        elseif(is_string($var[0]) && ctype_digit($var[0])){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    elseif(is_string($var)){
        if(ctype_digit($var)){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    elseif(is_int($var)){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Перебирая массив переменных:

```
$arr = array(
    0=>123,
    1=>'123',
    2=>array(123),
    3=>array('123'),
    4=>'123test',
    5=>array('123test'),
    6=>0,
    7=>NULL,
    8=>'',
    9=>array(1,2,3)
);
```

ответ такой:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Можно ли использовать этот код в проекте, либо стоит использовать регулярные выражения?

Comment: А в PHP нельзя использовать что-то вроде `return(ctype_digit($var))` вместо длинного `if (ctype_digit($var)) { return true; } else { return false; }?`

Comment: 1=>'123' - строка, а не int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код адекватный по подходу, но неоптимальный по реализации.
Зачем писать все проверки по два раза? Почему бы сначала не вытащить из массива значение, и дальше работать с ним как со скаляром?

```
function isint($var)
{
    if(is_array($var))
    {
        if (count($var) == 1 && is_scalar(reset($var)))
        {
            $var = current($var);
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return (is_int($var) || (is_string($var) && ctype_digit($var)));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв, буду оптимизировать код, либо использовать регулярку. Регулярное выражение применяется сейчас, просто наткнулся на возможную реализацию и решил задать вопрос тут.